# Using nested values defined in environment

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I have the following helmfile

```
releases:
  - name: whoami-mn
    namespace: whoami-mn-{{ .Environment.Name }}
    chart: tons/whoami-mn
    version: {{ .Values.chartVersions.whoami }}
    installed: {{ .Values.installed }}
    values:
      - env/{{ .Environment.Name }}-values.yaml

environments:
  dev:
    values:
      - installed: true
      - chartVersions:
          whoami: 0.3.0
          otherApp: 0.2.0
  prod:
    values:
      - installed: true
      - chartVersions:
          whoami: 0.2.0
          otherApp: 0.1.0
```

But when running `helmfile -e dev template` I get the following error
`in ./helmfile.yaml: error during helmfile.yaml.part.0 parsing: template: stringTemplate:5:23: executing "stringTemplate" at <.Values.chartVersions.whoami>: map has no entry for key "chartVersions"`

I can do something like the following

```
environments:
  dev:
    values:
      - installed: true
      - chartVersionWhoami: 0.3.0
```

That works but I'd prefer having all chart version grouped under a parent key. Any suggestions about how to get the former working?

UPDATE:
The following works

```
...
version: {{ (index .Values "chartVersions").whoamiMn }}
...
```

With the environment defined like the following

```
environments:
  dev:
    values:
      - installed: true
      - chartVersions:
          whoamiMn: 0.3.0
```

But I really feel like my first attempt should work as well!

Comment: did you try with `index` function: `{{index .Values.chartVersions "whoami"}}` ?

Comment: @AnnaSlastnikova - I actually did! The result is the same

Comment: hm I suspect it's limitation of helm file, there's a similar issue https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/issues/1418 might be worth escalating it or creating another one

Comment: Does explicitly specifying an environment `helmfile -e dev template` work?

Comment: @AnnaSlastnikova - Seems so, thanks for chipping in

Comment: @DavidMaze - No, and that is actually what I'm doing. I'll update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting and discussing further [here](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/issues/1418). I figured out that I can fix this issue by simply listing my `environments` before my `releases`. In my pedantic point of view I'd appreciate having my `releases` listed first but it works.